# Finding arbitrary/random repetitive patterns in signals (both self and across two signals)

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals, signal-detection, machine-learning, pattern

I am trying to figure out a direction for my research. I need to find random repetitive patterns between two signals and on each individual signal. I have read about FFT and time series-motif discovery(matrix profiles). Is there a concrete way (maybe using machine learning or some regret reward methods) to find "Unknown patterns" in signals in general.

[image]

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Hi Shravan K. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Given that shortcoming on my part, I suggest you study the processes of autocorrelation and correlation.

Comment: I understand the concepts of auto and cross correlations but I am not sure how we will be able to find patterns using cross correlation? can you explain more?